# How to make a command line app using node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I would like to build make command line app and it can be installed by npm.
Like express, after I `npm install express-generator -g`, I can use `express` as a command.
How do I make an app like this?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps.